# Swift navigation bar under status bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Here is what my navigation bar and status bar look like:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/m0SJxV5.png]

How do I prevent the navigation bar going under the status bar **without** using a navigation controller?

Comment: if you're not using a navigation controller.. what are you using to show the navigation bar?

Comment: @AkshanshThakur I just dropped a navigation bar into the storyboard

Comment: you need to give 20 px up constraint in order to avoid this behavior, or if you are using a custom view to do this, you need to give 64px of height

Comment: @ReinierMelian ok how do i do that?

Comment: You add a navigation bar or a search bar?

Comment: @ReinierMelian That is a navigation bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### EDITED

Check this image, you need to add a constraint on top to View to 0 and height = 64, and this is it

[image]

I hope this helps

Comment: yes that helps but the background color for the status bar and the navigation bar is different

Comment: then you need to put your height 64px, I will post another image

Comment: @ReinierMelian thoughts on a solution if we're not using autolayout?

Comment: @maxhs then you need modify the frame adding +20 on y origin

Comment: makes sense, @ReinierMelian, but then I have the issue of adding 20 points of padding between the top of the viewport and the navigation bar, which means what had previously been an opaque status bar and navigation bar from y origin 0 to 64 (height) now has 20 points of padding, making the content underneath (in this case, a tableView) visible. any way to avoid that?

Comment: I don´t understand your problem, can you post an image on igmur to see your issue?, one image worth more than thousand words @maxhs

Comment: 1. the easy but dumb solution would be to add a 20pt view and make it the same background color as the custom navigation bar to give the appearance. 2. would be custom subclass of uinavigationbar and override layout subviews.

Comment: does that illustrate the problem @ReinierMelian ?

Comment: Yes, but behind your custom navigation bar, what is that? your TableView content? @maxhs

Comment: yeah, that's tableView content behind the navBar @ReinierMelian

Comment: I suggest you, add a UIView as subView of your UIViewController.view, and inside that view add your navigationBar and your tableView, after that you only need to move that view.origin y + 20 and problem solved @maxhs

Comment: unfortunately that wouldn't work here because we still do want content to show underneath the status bar when the tableview is at certain scroll positions, @ReinierMelian

Comment: then add a content inset and problem solved, something like `self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)` must work for you @maxhs let me know

Comment: nope, it still creates 20 points of padding where I don't actually want that padding. appreciate your thoughts, though, @ReinierMelian!